# Test GraphQL in AWS Unauthorized 401, problem with Authorizer

Tags: postman, apollo-server, aws-serverless

With `Serverless` I have this config:

```
functions:
  my-account:
    handler: src/index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /my-account
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: authorizer
            arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:${self:provider.region}:XXXXXX:userpool/${self:custom.YYYY.cognito.userpool}
```

I'm trying to test with Postman but I got an:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I don't get what kind of Authorization it needs. I don't have API KEYs, I have a token in the app that consume that graphql, I put it as a "Bearer Token" but it still fails. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make a call first to Cognito to get a JWT token, then pass this in the request Authorization header as Bearer. I haven't used this route, but there's an API that does just that: [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html)